# Irreducible polynomial with coeficients in an UFD is primitive

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, irreducible-polynomials, unique-factorization-domains

How do you prove that, given a UFD polynomial ring, every irreducible polynomial is a primitive one. I am trying the following:

Let $R$ be a UFD, and $p\in R[X]$ be irreducible. We have the following:

$$p = c(p)\cdot p^*$$

where $c(p)\in R$, is a mcd of the coeficients of $p$, and $p^*$ is a primitive polynomial given by $p^* = p\cdot c(p)^{-1}$. Because $p$ is irreducible, then $c(p)$ is invertible or $p^*$ is invertible.

If $c(p)$ is invertible, we have by definition that $p$ is primitive.

What happens if $p^*$ is invertible?

I can't seem to find any argument to finish of the proof.

Comment: $R$ is a domain, so under what circumstances is a $f(x) \in R[x]$ invertible?

Comment: For $f(x)\in R[x]$ to be invertible, in a domain, then $f$ must be a constant,  $a$ and in particular, an invertible element of $R$

Comment: This is correct, so in this case isn't $p \in R$?

Comment: Yes, but I can't seem to see why that implies that $c(p)$ is invertible